# JavaScript Callback & Scope(referencing the right thing)

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, extjs, callback

My overall goal is to make the specified animal(cat1) make a sound(alert box) and get another specific animal(dog1) to listen for the cat to make a sound and reply with his sound.

In the following code I tried using the bind command to implement my callback.

```
Ext.define('Animal', 
    {
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Unknown',
        listening: this.listening,
        constructor: function(name) 
        {
            if (name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
        },
        makeSound: function() 
        {
            alert(this.name + " says " + this.sound);
            if(this.listening)
            {
                this.listening();
            }
        },
        isListening: function(listening)
        {
            this.listening = listening;
        }
    });

Ext.define('Cats',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Meow',
        listening: this.listening,
        listen: function()
        {
            if(this.listening)
                alert(this.name + "is listening.");
        }
    });
Ext.define('Dogs',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Woof',
        listening: this.listening,
        listen: function()
        {
            if(this.listening)
                alert(this.name + "is listening.");
        }
    });
var cat1 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Domino');
var cat2 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Tiger');
var dog1 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Bruno');
var dog2 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Spot');

dog1.listen = dog1.listen.bind(dog1); //failed miserably, not sure of the proper usage,
cat1.isListening(dog1.listen);        //I saw an example using this format.
cat1.makeSound();
cat2.makeSound();
dog1.makeSound();
dog2.makeSound();
```

This of course didn't work for me but it might be as simple as an incorrect usage of the bind command(no errors in the console make that hard to tell sometimes)
The way I really want to accomplish this is the following:(comments in code below explain it pretty well)

```
Ext.define('Animal', 
    {
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Unknown',
        listening: this.listening,
        constructor: function(name) 
        {
            if (name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
        },
        makeSound: function() 
        {
            alert(this.name + " says " + this.sound);
        },
        listen: function(obj)
        {
            if(this.listening)
                alert(obj.name + " is listening to " + this.name + ".");
        }
    });

Ext.define('Cats',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Meow',
    });
Ext.define('Dogs',
    {
        extend: 'Animal',
        name: 'Unknown',
        sound: 'Woof',
    });
var cat1 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Domino');
var cat2 = Ext.create('Cats', 'Tiger');
var dog1 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Bruno');
var dog2 = Ext.create('Dogs', 'Spot');

//some callback that will wait for a specific animal to make a sound
//and call the listen function in an intelligent way so I get this.name
//to be the animal that made that sound and the obj.name to be the 
//animal that is listening

cat1.makeSound();
cat2.makeSound();
dog1.makeSound();
dog2.makeSound();
```

This requires me to use the right scope, which of course I have no idea how to handle. 
Mainly I was hoping for some help in this area while staying away from custom events for callbacks.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use events instead. Ext.util.Observable does all that and more for you.

Comment: Yeah, i did end up using the Observable class to handle it. Thanks.